# Deserializing JSON object and Query

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to query for and get the matched JSON string. Following is my JSON:

I need to query the JSON I receive in the `HTTP RESPONSE`, match the JSON where `code=2`, then extract the `text=Jenny kisworth`

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "code":1234,
    "parentCode":9898,
    "language":{
      "lookup": "IN",
      "code": 1
    },
    "parentType": "Patient",
    "text": "James Berth"
  },
  {
    "code":4567,
    "parentCode":8989,
    "language":{
      "lookup": "IN",
      "code": 1
    },
    "parentType": "Patient",
    "text": "James Bond"
  },
 {
    "code":89101,
    "parentCode":2525,
    "language":{
      "lookup": "OUT",
      "code": 2
    },
    "parentType": "Patient",
    "text": "Jenny kisworth"
  }
]
```

**CODE:**

```
public class JSonData
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("code")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("language")]
        public List<Datum> language { get; set; }

    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string lookup { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }
    }

//only posting code relevant to the subject
HttpResponseMessage responseCode = client.GetAsync(codeParameters).Result;
if (responseCode.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var dataObjects = responseAlternateTitles.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dataObjects.Wait();

            string dataObjectsString = dataObjects.Result.ToString();
            var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSonData>>(dataObjectsString);
}
```

In the above I get an error: `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BCMTest.Datum]' because the type requires a JSON array`

Comment: `Datum` doesn't look right. Specifically `public string language { get; set; }` also it shouldn't be a list

Comment: That was a typo. I have modified it, it's actually `Language ->lookup,code`. Then I need to match on the `code` and find the match and extract that Object.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes should look more like this, how do i know? http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Language
{
    public string lookup { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class JSonData
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public int parentCode { get; set; }
    public Language language { get; set; }
    public string parentType { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

...

var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSonData>>(dataObjectsString);
```

Comment: Yes that helps but doesn't answer the complete question. So given you points for that

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because your JSON doesnot have a object of array in language as you are expecting in your class object.

Change the `JSonData class -> language`

```
public class JSonData
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("code")]
    public string code { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("language")]
    public Datum language { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: modified that, it was a typo, lets focus on fetching the json object as in my question

Comment: I'm getting an error on the `data`, as shown in my question

Comment: @user726720 Updated the answer

Comment: Yes that helps but doesn't answer the complete question. So given you points for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Language
{
    public string lookup { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class JSonData
{
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("code")]
    public string code { get; set; }
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("parentCode")]
     public int parentCode { get; set; }
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("language")]
    public Language language { get; set; }
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("parentType")]
    public string parentType { get; set; }
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("text")]
    public string text { get; set; }
}

var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSonData>>(dataObjectsString);
var filtereddata = data.Where(s => s.language.code.Equals(2));
```

Comment: Both Muhammad Saqlain, TheGeneral inspired this answer.